# Check columns for consistency / plausibility

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset (survey panel data) that contains a question like `"Have you ever been sad in your life? (100 = 'not sad', 0 = 'really sad"` which was asked 4 years in a row and I want to check if a person who has been sad in his life in year one still answers correctly in year 2, 3 and 4.

```
    A    B    C   D
0  100  100  100  75
1  75   75   75   75
2  50   100  75   100
3  100  75   50   25
4  100  -    -    75
```

In theory I have to check if all subsequent values in a row of the specified columns are <= the value of the previous column or nAn and if nAn compares to the last existing value. This would lead to

i[0] = True, i[1] = True, i[2] = False, i[3] = True and i[4] = True

The only solution I have on my mind would be to loop over every (5000) row, storing the value of column A in a variable and comparing that to column B and if B <= A, replace the stored value and continue. If at any point <= previous column does not hold, the condition is False and the next iteration starts.

Is there a simpler / less iterative approach? Thanks and have a nice evening :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, [`DataFrame.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) with [`DataFrame.le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) to check:

```
 #df = df.replace('-',np.nan).astype(float) #if nnecesary
 df['label'] = df.ffill(axis=1).diff(axis=1).fillna(0).le(0).all(axis=1)
 #or select the columns

 #df['label'] = (df[mylist].ffill(axis=1).diff(axis=1)
 #                         .fillna(0).le(0).all(axis=1))
```

---

```
       A      B      C      D  label
0  100.0  100.0  100.0   75.0   True
1   75.0   75.0   75.0   75.0   True
2   50.0  100.0   75.0  100.0  False
3  100.0   75.0   50.0   25.0   True
4  100.0    NaN    NaN   75.0   True
```